# Show that the Cauchy principal value of $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx$ exists when $\mbox{deg}(Q)=\mbox{deg}(P)+1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Let $R=\frac{P}{Q}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials such that $Q$ has not zeros in $\mathbb{R}$ and   $\mbox{deg}(Q)=\mbox{deg}(P)+1$. Show that the Cauchy principal value of $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R(x)dx$ exists, that is,

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}R(x)dx  \qquad \mbox{exists.}$$

**Remark:** I know that $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}\frac{\hat{P}(x)}{\hat{Q}(x)}dx $  exists when we have $\mbox{deg}(\hat{Q})\geq\mbox{deg}(\hat{P})+2$ then considering $P(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$ and $Q(x)=b_{0}+b_{1}x+\cdots+b_{n}x^{n}+b_{n+1}x^{n+1}$, we have

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}R(x)dx=\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}\frac{a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}}{Q(x)}dx+\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}\frac{a_{n}x^{n}}{Q(x)}dx
$$

Note that $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}\frac{a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}}{Q(x)}dx $ exists. So my problem is summarized to show that $ \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-s}^{s}\frac{a_{n}x^{n}}{Q(x)}dx $ exists, for this purpose, I have tried to consider the curve $\gamma=\gamma_{1}+\gamma_{2}$ where $\gamma_{2}(t)=se^{it}$ where $t\in[0,\pi]$ is the semicircle and $\gamma_{1}(t)=t$  is the segment joining $-s$ with $s$ the problem is in show that
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma_{2}}\frac{a_{n}z^{n}}{Q(z)}dz=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may assume that the leading coefficient of $P$ and $Q$ is $1$. Let $d$ be the degree of $P$ and $Q=x\,P+p$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d$. Then
$$
\frac PQ=\frac1x-\frac{p}{x\,Q}.
$$
The principal value of $1/x$ exists, and $p/(x\,Q)$ is integrable since the degree of $p$ is at most $d$ and the degree of $x\,Q$ is $d+2$.

Added to answer Diego's comment:

Let
$$\begin{align}
P(x)&=x^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0\\
Q(x)&=x^{d+1}+b_dx^d+\dots+b_1x+b_0\\
p(x)&=Q(x)-x\,P(x)=(b_d-a_{d-1})x^d+\dots(b_1-a_0)x+b_0.
\end{align}$$
Now
$$
\frac{P}{Q}=\frac1x\,\frac{x\,P}{Q}=\frac1x\,\frac{x\,P+p-p}{x\,P+p}=\frac1x\Bigl(1-\frac pQ\Bigr).
$$
Example:
$$
\frac{x+2}{x^2+3\,x+1}=\frac1x-\frac{x+1}{x(x^2+3\,x+1)}.
$$

Comment: Why do you say $\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{p}{xQ}$? We really have $\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{1}{x+c}-\frac{p}{ (x+c) Q}$ where $c$ can not be zero. What happens in this case? Why you omit $c$?

Comment: I have explained in the answer.